# ASP.NET webapi HttpResponseMessage with ExecuteReaderAsync CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I need to stream blob data from Sql Server via WebApi.

I DONT want to buffer the blob data in memory on the web server.

I have the following code, but it does not work - there is NO exception.

```
public class AttachmentController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int id)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Content FROM [Attachments] WHERE ID = @ID", connection))
            {

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", id);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                {

                    if (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        using (Stream data = reader.GetStream(0))
                        {
                            var response = new HttpResponseMessage{Content = new StreamContent(data)};
                            //I get this from the DB else where
                            //response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(attachment.ContentType);
                            //I get this from the DB else where
                            //response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = attachment.ContentLength;
                            return response;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle writes the following error as the reposnse:
[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.

How can I stream the content from the DB to the http output stream, with out buffering it in memory?

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the stream before ASP.NET MVC has finished reading from it. It will be closed once you leave the various using blocks which happens right after the `return` statement has executed.

I know of no easy way to accomplish this. The best idea would be to write a custom `Stream`-derived class that wraps the stream returned by ADO.NET and once the stream is depleted disposes of everything (the `Stream`, the reader, the command and the connection).

This solution would mean that you cannot use using blocks and such. I really don't like it but I cannot think of something better at the moment. The requirements are difficult in combination: you want streaming behavior and need to dispose of the various resources you opened.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar: create a custom class derived from `StreamContent` that overrides the `Dispose()` method.